# Composite pattern with GUI

Tags: design-patterns, user-interface

I'm having issues with designing a GUI for my game.  So far, I've come to the conclusion that the **Composite Pattern** is going to allow me to treat all **UIComponents** the same regardless if one is a **UIButton** and the other is a **UIMenu**.  Here is the UIComponent interface:

```
class UIComponent {
   virtual void Init() = 0;
   virtual void Draw() = 0;
}
```

Each of my implementing classes (**UIFrame, UIButton, UITextBox, UIMenu, ...**) can now work with one another.  The composite class in this design is the UIMenu class because it **IS A** UIComponent and **HAS A** UIComponent.

```
class UIMenu : public UIComponent {
   private:
      vector<UIComponent*> children_;

   public:
      virtual void Init() {
         // Initialize any data
      };

      virtual void Draw() {
         // Delegate drawing to each child
         for each(UIComponent* component in children_) {
            component->Draw();
         }
      };

      void AddComponent(UIComponent* child) {...};
      void RemoveComponent(UIComponent* child) {...};
}
```

Because I want to support drag-n-drop functionality amongst all the **UIComponents**, each and every component will need Position, Dimensions, Scale, Parent, and Layer (**ComponentData**).  To do that, I would need to add them separately to each implementing class which, to me, seems like the wrong way to do it.

```
class UIFrame : public UIComponent {
   private:
      string imgID_;

      int layer_;
      double relX_, relY_;
      double width_, height_;
      double scaleX_, scaleY_;

      UIComponent* parent_;
   public:
      virtual void Init() {...}
      virtual void Draw() {...}

      ...
};
```

Doesn't this already break the Composite Pattern since I have now made each and every component implementation a composite via aggregation?  If I wanted my UIButtons to have the same ability to be positioned, transformed, and scaled, I would need to either inherit from UIFrame or copy the data members into UIButton.

Is there a better way to create the implementations of the **UIComponent** interface?  For example, instead of UIButton, UITextBox, UILabel, etc, we could have UIFrame be the base class for all components that require the ability to move.  Now, components like UIButton will be children of UIFrame in order to reuse the ComponentData.

Would it be better to place the methods involved with positioning, transforming, and scaling in the UIComponent interface?  This would enforce that every component knows how to manipulate itself on screen.  However, I'm still left with the question, "Where do I put the ComponentData (position, dimensions, scale)?"

I really like the idea of the Composite Pattern and the ability to treat Leaf and Branch nodes of a Tree structure atomically.  It also allows me to use the **Decorator Pattern** to create multiple iterations of UIMenu objects so I can have an InventoryMenu, CharacterInfoMenu, OptionsMenu, etc all by changing what UIComponents each Menu has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a super class `UIDraggable` with the data items and methods you need to support drag and drop and each draggable element can inherit it.  `UIDraggable` can inherit `UIComponent`.